# Prefered way to pass a const reference/pointer to a class for storing, not to copy the referred object

Tags: c++, const-reference, const-pointer

Example:

```
class Bar;

class Foo
{
public:

    Foo(const Bar& bar) : mBar(&bar) {}

    /* Other methods use mBar. */

private:

    const Bar* mBar;
};
```

So the goal is to store a const pointer to some external object, not to store a copy of the external object's contents.

- Pass by const reference: `Foo(const Bar& bar)`

  - Common idiom to pass a object to a constructor, many programmers will think the Foo will store a copy of the Bar rather then the pointer/reference itself.
  - Caller can pass a temporary. This can be prevented by deleting the r-value overload `Foo(const Bar&&) = delete`. However this isn't fool-proof as you can still smuggle in temporaries via a function that takes a const reference and returns a const reference. `Foo afoo(std::min(Bar{}, anotherBar));` for example.
- Pass by const pointer: `Foo(const Bar* bar)`

  - Must check for nullptr, which is a runtime check, compile time mechanisms are preferred.
  - Can still smuggle in temporaries: `Foo afoo(&std::min(Bar{}, anotherBar));`

Which of the above is preferred and why? Or are there any better ways to do this that do not suffer from the above problems ?

Comment: The most clear semantics could be expressesd with smart pointers IMO.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ But the `Bar` reference/pointer to be passed in need not necessarily be dynamically allocated.

Comment: This looks like an opinion-based question. So in my opinion, taking a pointer as parameter is the way to go, since that's what you're actually doing (storing a pointer to an object.) Document it must not be null and throw an exception in the constructor if it is null. Since `Foo` stores a pointer to an externally managed object, the user of `Foo` has to be responsible for avoiding breakage. I don't see a way around that. If that's not good enough, then the only option is to restructure your design so that no pointer to an external object is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can accept a `::std::reference_wrapper<Bar>`, it will handle case with passing an rvalue as well as provide a hint that you are aming to copy wrapper rather than the object.

Comment: That suffers from the same problem as detailed in the question. One can still smuggle a temporary into the reference wrapper. `Foo afoo(std::cref(std::min(Bar{}, anotherBar)));`. But it is more descriptive indeed.